# mysqli return data in multiple rows with same id

Tags: php, mysql

hello so here is what I have in a table called "members"

```
id - key - value
1    name  john
1    age   35
1    zip   12345
2    name  stacy
2    age   22
2    zip   11223
3    name  mark
3    age   44 
3    ssn   11111111
3    zip   54321
```

I am trying to return this data in this manner:

```
1 - john - 35 - 12345
2 - stacey - 22- 11223
etc... (its a longer list)
```

I need it in this format that way I can insert it into another table using a loop.
any ideas on how I can do that ?

```
$resultat = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM members'");
```

this will get all members. I am not sure how to go about doing what i need 
any input would be greatly appreciated thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of pivoting the data.  Here is one method:

```
select m.id,
       max(case when key = 'name' then value end) as name,
       max(case when key = 'age' then value end) as age,
       max(case when key = 'zip' then value end) as zip
from members m
group by id;
```

Comment: very interesting. what would that return ?

Comment: @fogsy . . . This should return data in the format that you want it in.

Comment: @GordonLinoff while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultat)) {echo $row['email'];} this returns Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in

Comment: Your question doesn't appear to be about how "mysqli_" works.  It appears to be about how to write the query.  If you need help with "mysqli_" ask another question and tag it appropriately.